# Adding a border on each page

Tags: border, page

I want to add page border in each of my project's report page.  If there is any command in sharelatex then let me know about it or else just give me some solution for it.

Comment: What sort of border?  Somthing like https://openclipart.org/tags/Borders%20and%20Frames ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution based on the packages `eso-pic` and `calc`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}

\setlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}{1cm}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\Page@FrameHeight}
\newlength{\Page@FrameWidth}

\AddToShipoutPicture{
  \thinlines
  \setlength{\Page@FrameHeight}{\paperheight-\PageFrameTopMargin-\PageFrameBottomMargin}
  \setlength{\Page@FrameWidth}{\paperwidth-\PageFrameLeftMargin-\PageFrameRightMargin}
  \put(\strip@pt\PageFrameLeftMargin,\strip@pt\PageFrameTopMargin){
    \framebox(\strip@pt\Page@FrameWidth, \strip@pt\Page@FrameHeight){}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following result.

[image: Output of the MWE.]

You can change the values for `\PageFrameTopMargin`, `\PageFrameBottomMargin`, `\PageFrameLeftMargin` and `\PageFrameRightMargin` in the preamble as needed.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this if the background of the page is colored?  It seems that the color overrides the border.

Comment: @Matthias Please tell me, How to increase the width of the frame or line??

Comment: @limlan You can use `\thicklines` instead of `\thinlines`. As far as I know the fine-tuning options are quite limited using the `eso-pic` package. TikZ might be a better alternative.