# Page Borders on Specific Pages, followup to an answer from another question

Tags: border

I tried using the answer from [Adding a border on each page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404749/adding-a-border-on-each-page) to create a page border, and it works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the page border from certain pages?

I would ask this in a comment, but unfortunately I don't have 50 reputation :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an expanded version of the answer you quote.

```
% noborderprob.tex SE 559677

% the following code mainly from SE 404749
\documentclass{article}

% PW added the folowing code
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{borderon} 
\newcommand{\borders}{\setboolean{borderon}{true}}    % have borders
\newcommand{\noborders}{\setboolean{borderon}{false}} % no borders
\borders
% end of addition

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}

\setlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}{1cm}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\Page@FrameHeight}
\newlength{\Page@FrameWidth}

% PW modified the \AddToShipoutPicture to output nothing for borderon=false
\AddToShipoutPicture{
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{borderon}}{%
  \thinlines
  \setlength{\Page@FrameHeight}{\paperheight-\PageFrameTopMargin-\PageFrameBottomMargin}
  \setlength{\Page@FrameWidth}{\paperwidth-\PageFrameLeftMargin-\PageFrameRightMargin}
  \put(\strip@pt\PageFrameLeftMargin,\strip@pt\PageFrameTopMargin){
    \framebox(\strip@pt\Page@FrameWidth, \strip@pt\Page@FrameHeight){}}}
{}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

% PW added the following code

\lipsum 

\lipsum 

\noborders % stop page borders

\lipsum

\borders % start page borders

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This starts off with pages having borders. To stop the bordering put `\noborders` on the page which you want to be borderless. Put `\borders` on the page where you want bordering to start again.